# How can i compute the difference of two vectors with missing values?

Tags: r

Good afternoon !

Assume we have two vectors with missing values:

```
c(4,NA,1)-c(5,6,NA)
[1] -1 NA NA
```

I'm searching a way to get the following output instead :

```
[1] -1 -6 1
```

This means replacing `NA` values with `zeros`.

I'm searching a built-in or efficient way to do it!

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is `rowSums` by `cbind`ing the two `vector`s (second with the sign changed) and make use of the `na.rm` argument

```
rowSums(cbind(c(4, NA, 1), -c(5, 6, NA)), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] -1 -6  1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_1 <-  c(4,NA,1)
df_2 <- c(5,6,NA)

df_1 <- df_1 %>% replace_na(0)
df_2 <- df_2 %>% replace_na(0)


df_1 - df_2
```